# Python - Prime numbers Code

Tags: python, prime-factoring

I'm trying to find a prime factor of the number 705561475143.

In my code, the function `primeFactor()` searches for all the factors in a certain integer, plugs them into the function `Prime()`, which either changes the number into 0 or doesn't change it at all. If the number isn't changed to 0, it's a prime number that should be added to the list.

```
import math


def Prime(n):
    isPrime = False
    r = range(2, int(math.sqrt(n)+5))
    a = 1
    for b in r:
        if r[a] >= int(math.sqrt(n)+2):
            break
        elif n % r[a] != 0:
            a += 1
        elif n % r[a] == 0 & n != r[a] & n != 1:
            n = 0
            break

def primeFactor(m):
    l = []
    for x in range(1, m+1):
        if m % x == 0:
            if Prime(m) != 0:
                l.append(x)
    print(l)
```

However, when I input

```
> primeFactor(36)
```

I get

```
> [1,2,3,4,6,9,12,18,36]
```

Instead of

```
> [2,3]
```

And when I input

```
> primeFactor(705561475143)
```

The code cannot give me an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, why do you use `m+1` for the `x in range()`? Note, you might want to only use `range(2, m/2, 1)` - see if you can figure out why.

Secondly,

```
    if m % x == 0:
        if Prime(m) != 0:
            l.append(x)
```

If `m` is divisible by `x` then it can't be prime and calling `Prime(m)` is useless. I suspect you meant to pass `x` as the argument. (Assuming `x` is not 0 or `== m`)

Thirdly `Prime()` never returns anything. This means that it is always `!= 0`.

Finally, to help you out a bit, I'll [link you to some of my own answers to this question](https://gist.github.com/vikhik/7635565/).

Comment: Thanks. I tried running this, but it didn't recognize some functions (ie primeList). What imports did you additionally use?

Comment: @LaPXL8R - I purposefully did not include primeList(). I did however end up spending an hour or so tweaking my code to be more optimised, I will update this post now.